# 'Invalid Format' - Telegram BOT Token API - Telegram.Bot Package

Tags: c#, .net, telegram-bot

how're going?

I'm trying to start a Telegram Bot using Telegram.Bot package from NuGet on .NET Framework, and the bellow error is tanking place:[Error Telegram.Bot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05GtP.png)

This only happens with new bots created on Telegram Bot Father using the API Token to start the BOT and not happens with old BOTs.

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Same problem, but, as the warning messages also say while compiling the code, old versions will not work in future.
I advise you to check the new version (17.0.0 is the last).
Watch this video to see an example:
https://youtu.be/EJIur-6RqPY

There is also the Migration Guide:
https://telegrambots.github.io/book/Migration-Guide-to-Version-17.x.html